# SSIS. Stop running after 10pm

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package with a for loop.
I would like to keep the value "10pm" in my sql database, and I want the loop the check every time if it's after this value of "10pm" (or whatever i decide to put in the database). If the time now is after 10pm, then stop looping.

Thanks.

Comment: I know to use getDate() to get the full datetime, but i don't know how to ask if the time is after 10pm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an Execute SQl Task before For Loop .Write an expression to get the time .

```
select case
      when DATEPART(hour,getdate()) > 12 
      then Parsename(replace(LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100), 7)),':','.'),2)
      else 0
      End
```

Store the above value in a variable and in the precedence constraint check if the variable value is greater then 10 then Failure else success

```
@Variable>10
```